# django using another field instead of id in the url template tag

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.5

I have this block of code in a html file

```
{% for p in latest_posts %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' p.id %}">{{p.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

If i change p.id to p.title

```
{% for p in latest_posts %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' p.title %}">{{p.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

then I get the following error

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(u'Second post',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I want the url to be /title and not /id.

This is my urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('',

    url(r'^(?P<title>\w+)/$',
            PostDetailView.as_view(),
            name = 'detail'
        ),
)
```

Should I just use get_absolute_url?

**Update**

I added the slug field but it still doesn't work

```
{% url 'blog:detail' p.slug %}
```

The error I get is

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(u'third-post',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

**Post model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 225)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

The admin is updated

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug" : ("title",)}


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

If this works

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:detail' p.id %}">{{p.title}}</a>
```

why doesn't this work

```
<li><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' p.slug %}">{{p.title}}</a></li>
```

**update**

PostDetailView

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):

    template_name = 'blogapp/post/detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Post, slug__iexact = self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Comment: So you want the blog posts urls to be something like `/blog/second-post` instead of `/blog/2` ?

Comment: yes, I want the url to be /blog/second-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things you are going to want to look into is a [slugfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) which will allow you to have data that is capable of being used in a url. Slugs can contain only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. From there you will most likely want to override your model's `save` method to set and ensure the slugfield is unique. You can then use that field as an identifier for your url. You can then do something like `{% url 'blog:detail' slug=p.slug %}` assuming that you name the field `slug`. Also, as pointed out in another answer, if you do use this, you need to fix your url to look for a slug instead.

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('',

    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        PostDetailView.as_view(),
        name = 'detail'
    ),
```

)

Comment: I added the slug field to my model and updated admin.py to include slug in the prepopulated_fields dictionary. I changed the url template tag to {% url 'blog:detail' p.slug %} but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have my url incorrect... it should be url(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$',

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the generic detail view, it expects either an id or a slug value.

However, in your URL conf, you're specifying the named variable as 'title'.  Try changing it to 'slug':

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('',

    url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$',
            PostDetailView.as_view(),
            name = 'detail'
        ),
)
```

Comment: I still get the same error after replacing title with slug in urls.py. I updated the question showing PostDetailView